# How to open the Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts or Groups

Tags: windows, users

The only way I know how to open the Select Users, Computers, Service Accounts or Groups is by right clicking on a folder and selecting Properties -> Security Tab -> Edit -> Advanced.

Below is a screen shot of the window I want to access:

[image]

Is there any other way to view the full list which Find Now would bring up (ie, the list of all local/network users and groups)? I am writing documentation and I want the user to check if a user exists either locally or on the network before creating a new account/group. I would ideally like them to access this via control panel or similar (or command).

Comment: how many computers do you have?

Comment: Well, this would need to apply to home and work, but the principal I would have thought was the same. So, let's assume between 2 and 500.

Comment: Do you have a domain at work?(perhaps Yes, but please confirm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting you right and you want this just for local computer, then this'll do.
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and run `lusrmgr.msc`

Comment: Unless you do not a have domain, this can't be done.

Comment: Then you can use `cmd.exe` and `net user /domian`

Comment: This command will list all users in the domain, but not local user on each machine. Do you need local admins to be listed in your report?

Answer (score 3):

To search for active directory users you can open "Find Users, Contacts and Groups" window by using the following Run command: `rundll32.exe dsquery.dll,OpenQueryWindow`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/606351)

Comment: That command will open search for users in Active Directory as he asked "Is there any other way to view the full list which Find Now would bring up (ie, the list of all local/network users and groups)?"

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 7, click on Networks and then click on Active Directory.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use [SYDI server](http://sydiproject.com/products/sydi-server/), to be more precise ***sydi-wrapper.vbs*** and [***sydi-audit-localgroups.vbs***](http://sydiproject.com/tools/sydi-audit-localgroups/) tool.

First tool will allow you to collect reports from a list of servers in excel file or from a specific OU in a domain tree.

***sydi-wrapper description***

The script is included in the tools directory of SYDI Server. It allows to run SYDI against multiple computers. For that purpose you need to edit script for your configuration, specifying gathering options i.e. WMI-options, export formats, location options.

**Using the script:**

*Cscript.exe sydi-wrapper.vbs [options]*

**Examples**

*cscript.exe sydi-wrapper.vbs -tComputers.csv*

*cscript.exe sydi-wrapper.vbs -aDC=contoso,DC=com*

*cscript.exe sydi-wrapper.vbs -a”OU=Member Servers,DC=contoso,DC=com”*

***sydi-audit-localgroups description***

The script is included in the tools directory of SYDI Server. It works in the same way as SYDI Overview does. It parses SYDI-Server XML files and creates an Excel file containing a list of all your local groups on your client computers and member servers. The Excel file will have an overview sheet which lists all your groups and a separate sheet for each and every group.

**Using the script:**

*Cscript.exe sydi-audit-localgroups.vbs -xC:\SYDI\Output*

**Examples**

*cscript.exe sydi-overview.vbs -x"D:\sydi output"*

You will get an excel file with all of the groups available on the 1st sheet.
If you click on the link opposite to the Group Name you will have all the local users\groups listed for every server.

*The scripts will run and attempt to connect under logged in account, make sure this is domain one.